# Does a Large creature moving through a threatened area trigger Reactive Strike?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, opportunity-attack, reactions, reach

[image]

Consider a fighter (green), with a reach weapon (red), confronting an ogre (orange).  On the ogre's turn, it Strides five feet southeast and then five feet east, ending adjacent to the fighter.  Does this movement trigger Reactive Strike?

> REACTIVE STRIKE [reaction]
> Trigger A creature within your reach **uses** a manipulate action
> or **a move action**, makes a ranged attack, or **leaves a square
> during a move action it’s using**.
> You lash out at a foe that leaves an opening. Make a melee Strike
> against the triggering creature. If your attack is a critical hit and
> the trigger was a manipulate action, you disrupt that action.
> This Strike doesn’t count toward your multiple attack penalty,
> and your multiple attack penalty doesn’t apply to this Strike.
> [emphasis added]

Comment: small issue, not sure the second diagonal space is within a 10' reach, does not change the answer as the space bellow it is still within 10'

Comment: @CaptianObvious It absolutely is, see [the reach rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=352).

Comment: @CaptianObvious,it is _not_ in 10', but the reach rules make an exception for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, it leaves a square and triggers Reactive Strike.

It isn't in reach when it uses the move action, nor when it moves southeast, so that part of the action does not trigger Reactive Strike.  However, when it moves east, it leaves the two squares to the west of its final position.  Because the trigger mentions a "creature" within the fighter's reach and makes no reference to "squares" within their reach, the fact that the squares it's leaving are not themselves in the fighter's reach doesn't signify.

Comment: I do not really understand your argument about "the squares being out of reach", but the answer is correct even without that.